# ember vertical collection rendering only when clicked

Tags: ember.js

When I use the ember vertical collection from https://github.com/html-next/vertical-collection, it only renders new components when clicked on the screen, it does not render new components while scrolling. Here is the code below

```
{{#vertical-collection model estimateHeight=90 bufferSize=5 staticHeight=true lastReached="loadBelow" as |item|}}
        -----
    {{/vertical-collection}}
```

Comment: can you replicate in http://ember-twiddle.com/ or in a repro repo?  my hunch is that there is something going on unrelated the code provided, and maybe there is an error, state weirdness, or something causing something goofy to happen

Answer (score 1):

Check the container selector on which the scroll event is added. Faced a similar issue. The issue was that I had a parent container div which grows (flex-grow:1) and I passed the `containerSelector` as the child element which contained the `vertical-collection` component. Replaced it with the parent div selector and it works normal now.

```
<div class="inline-slider-header"></div>
<div class="inline-slider-body"> <!-- Has a styling of flex-grow:1 -->
  <div class="list-container">
    {{#vertical-collection this.items
      tagName="div"
      estimateHeight=47
      bufferSize=3
      containerSelector=".inline-slider-body"
      renderAll=false
      as |item index|
    }}
      <div class="item">
        <p>{{index}}</p>
        <p>{{item.title}}</p>
      </div>
    {{/vertical-collection}}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="inline-slider-footer"></div>
```